# Add DE row for first email in a Send Job using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I'm wanting to insert a row in a [Data Extension](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/) (DE) exactly once per email send using AMPScript -- *without using a lookup*.

The best I've been able to do is limit the upserts to the first Batch ID using the `_JobSubscriberBatchID` [personalization string](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/).

In analyzing tracking data, I've noticed that all non-triggered send jobs are separated into batches and numbered sequentially starting at `1`.  The batch sizes range from 50 to 500 emails.  So at most this operation would be done 500 times.

```
%%[

if _JobSubscriberBatchID == 1 then

  /* upsertDE() function goes here */

endif 

]%%
```

Anyone have a better way to go about this?

Answer (score -1):

Updated.

Have you maybe tried making it work with

```
%%before; httpget; 1 "http://URL_TO_CLOUD_PAGE"%%
```

and then create a Cloud Page with the `InsertData` AMPScript function?

Comment: I know about `_messagecontext`.  That's not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Updated the answer, maybe something like what I've outlined would help?